# XWPF POI footer different in last page

Tags: header, apache-poi, footer, xwpf

How to set footer diferrent only in last page. I mean, in last page no footer or different. in first page and other are same.

[enter link description here](http://xsatriya.net/xsatriya/download/FileSementara.docx)

[this is my docx](http://xsatriya.net/xsatriya/download/FileSementara.docx)

Answer (score 1):

There is not a header/footer only for the last page in Microsoft Word.

There are different header/footer settings possible for first page, even pages and default pages. There the default header/footer gets used for each pages if not else is defined. So if there is a header/footer for even pages and a setting that odd and even pages shall be different, then default header/footer gets used as header/footer for odd pages only. If there is no such setting, then the default header/footer gets used for each page. This is except first page, if there is a special header/footer for first page set.

But a Word document can be separated into different sections. And each section may have own header/footer settings. So if, and only if, the last page is in its own section, then there can be a different header/footer for the last page (last section) only.

Unfortunately `apache poi` do not provide methods to set sections in `XWPF`. And it only provides methods to set the three different header/footer types in document. So to get a `XWPFDocument` separated into sections and to set different header/footer settings for those sections, a little bit cheating is necessary.

One could create one of the three possible header/footer types only to set it to be the default header/footer for an own section later. The following example shows this. It creates a footer for even pages in document, which never gets used but later gets referenced as the default footer for the last section. Note the further comments in the code.

Of course that only can work if one at least knows where the last page starts. That must be known because the section break needs to be set before the content of the lase page.

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class CreateWordDifferentFooters {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  XWPFFooter footer;

  //create footers
  //footer for first page
  footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Footer FIRST");
  //default footer = footer for each what is not else defined
  footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Footer DEFAULT");
  //footer for even pages - gets default footer for page in last section later
  footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.EVEN);
  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Footer EVEN = DEFAULT in last section");

  //the body content
  //section 1
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("First page in first section ...");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Second page in first section ...");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Third page in first section ...");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //paragraph with section setting for section above and section break
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrSect1 = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr(); //we need ctSectPrSect1 later
  
  //section 2
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Fourth and last page. Only page in last section ...");
  
  //section setting for section above = last section in document
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrLastSect = ctBody.getSectPr(); //there must be a SectPr already because of the footer settings above
  
  //move first and default footer to section 1
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef0 = ctSectPrLastSect.getFooterReferenceArray(0); // first footer
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef1 = ctSectPrLastSect.getFooterReferenceArray(1); // default footer
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef[] ctHdrFtrRefs = new org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef[]{ctHdrFtrRef0, ctHdrFtrRef1};
  ctSectPrSect1.setFooterReferenceArray(ctHdrFtrRefs);
  //set "there is a title page" for section 1 to make first footer work
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff ctOnOff = org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
  ctOnOff.setVal(true);
  ctSectPrSect1.setTitlePg(ctOnOff);
  
  //set footer reference of even footer to be default footer reference for last section
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrLastSect.getFooterReferenceArray(2);
  ctHdrFtrRef.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.DEFAULT); //change this from STHdrFtr.EVEN to STHdrFtr.DEFAULT
  //unset "there is a title page" for the last section
  ctSectPrLastSect.unsetTitlePg();
  //remove first and old default footer references from last section
  ctSectPrLastSect.removeFooterReference(1);
  ctSectPrLastSect.removeFooterReference(0);
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordDifferentFooters.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

This is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.0`.

Comment: the problem, i dont know which text of paragraph are in the last page. So I dont know, which text n last section....

Comment: The method setVal(STOnOff.Enum) in the type CTOnOff is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Comment: @Eko: This is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.0`. Do using `ctOnOff.setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff.ON);` for former versions.

Comment: ok. i use poi 4

Comment: the problem, i dont know which text of paragraph are in the last page. So I dont know, which text n last section

Comment: Actually, I want to send to you example with docx format. You can analyse what  I mean. But I dont know how to send them

Comment: @Eko: You can't send me something. But you could ask a question and link a document which you had uploaded somewhere. But do asking a new question as this question is answered already. And please do more effort to your questions. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - especially **Help others reproduce the problem**.

Comment: http://xsatriya.net/xsatriya/download/FileSementara.docx

Comment: i wait your solving my problem. thanks

Comment: @Eko: I looked at your Word document. But using `apache poi` I am afraid it will not be possible reproducing this exactly as it is. To reproduce this, a human brain is needed which decides where to insert hyphens, paragraph breaks, additional spaces and where to anchor the line shapes. In other words, a human needs to sit in front of a monitor on which that document gets viewed in Word GUI and needs to work with that Word GUI then. And I suspect exactly that is the aim of those marks though? To get a review proof from a human reader. No?

Comment: yes, you are right, but there are aplication that work like that. but the app use macro in ws word feature.

Comment: I want to make app like that but use java web.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWopbRx-flo

Comment: maybe, for step by step :

Comment: 1. I must know text position in what page/page number, 2. must know text position in top and bottom of every page.

Comment: @Eko: Determining text positions on pages needs rendering the document. `Apache poi` does not rendering the document. So, what you want is not possible using `apache poi`.

Comment: if not possible, anyway what must i use

Comment: what about XWPFWordExtractor

Comment: I upgrade from poi 4 to poi 5, have error...why...