# Apache POI - Add page to docx without header

Tags: apache-poi

Good day!
Please help me find a solution to my problem:
I need to add a new QR page to the document and save it in a new form in a new directory. I manage to do it, except for one nuance. The source document has a header that is automatically added when adding a new page, as it is the default. The problem is that I do not need this header in the added page with a QR, but I need to save it in all the others. I need to have a last page without a header.
If i use this

```
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
policy.getHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT).clearHeaderFooter();
```

This removes the header on all pages, which is expected. If I use this:

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph0 = document.createParagraph();
XWPFParagraph paragraph1 = document.createParagraph();
// Working with paragraphs

XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();

XWPFParagraph[] pars = new XWPFParagraph[2];
pars[0] = paragraph0;
pars[0] = paragraph1;

XWPFHeader header = policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, pars);
header.clearHeaderFooter();
```

That happens exactly the same thing, namely, the header is removed from all pages.

Please help me add a new page with paragraphs without a header, keeping the header on all pages of the original document.
Thank you very much!

Comment: "need to have a last page without a header": See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325868/xwpf-poi-footer-different-in-last-page/71333447#71333447 for how to set footer different in last page. It's the same for the header.

Comment: @axel-richter - Thanks a lot for the example! It was very useful for me to learn this approach. If you create a document from scratch, then everything works as described by you. Unfortunately, it has not yet been possible to adapt your code to my needs. I have the following task:
• Open an existing document that contains information and two types of header (FIRST & DEFAULT)
• It is necessary to add an image with a QR to this finished document so that it is always on a new page and without a header
The default header is a table. Your method does not remove it (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a header/footer only for the last page in Microsoft Word.

In [XWPF POI footer different in last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325868/xwpf-poi-footer-different-in-last-page/71333447#71333447) I have shown how to set a footer different in last page. It's the same for the header.

My code in the linked answer is as short as possible to show the principle. As with all code in answers here, it is **not** thought to be usable as productive code per copy/paste. It is thought to be usable to test and understand. Code for productive usage of course must contain much more checks to consider all possible different options a reals Word document might use. But such code often is much too broad to get the principles.

From your question (and comment), the requirement is as follows:

Open an existing document that contains information and two types of header (FIRST & DEFAULT). Then add a new page without a header as the last page in the document.

So the principle is the same. We need to:

1. Adding a header for even pages, which gets the default header for
   page in last section later.
2. Adding a paragraph with section settings for section 1 above and
   section break.
3. Adding the content for new section 2.
4. Getting the old section settings for last section in document which
   contains the old header/footer settings too.
5. Moving the first and default headers and all footers from last
   section to new section 1.
6. Setting "there is a title page" for section 1 to make first header
   work. Removing first and old default header references from last
   section (now section 2) and setting header reference of even header
   to be the default header reference for this last section.
7. Unset "there is a title page" for the last section.

The following complete example shows this again. It is tested and works using current  `apache poi 5.2.2` and a `WordDocumentSource.docx` which contains multiple pages having default content and header/footer for first page and default pages.

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class WordAddLastPageWithoutHeader {
    
 private static void addLastPageInSeparateSection(XWPFDocument document) {
     
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  XWPFHeader header;
  
  //Adding a header for even pages, which gets the default header for page in last section later.
  header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.EVEN);
  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Header EVEN = DEFAULT in last section"); // don't set text here if you wants the header of the page in last section empty.

  //Adding a paragraph with section settings for section 1 above and section break.
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrSect1 = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr(); //we need ctSectPrSect1 later to set headers/footes
 
  //Adding the content for new section 2.
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Last page. Page in last section ...");
  //ToDo: further content of last page in separate section
  
  //Getting the old section settings for last section in document which contains the old header/footer settings too.
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrLastSect = ctBody.getSectPr(); //there must be a SectPr already because of the header/footer settings

  //Moving the first and default headers and all footers from last section to new section 1.
  java.util.List<org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef> ctHdrFtrRefList = new java.util.ArrayList<org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef>();
  for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef : ctSectPrLastSect.getHeaderReferenceList()) {
   if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.FIRST)
    ctHdrFtrRefList.add(ctHdrFtrRef);
   if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.DEFAULT)
    ctHdrFtrRefList.add(ctHdrFtrRef);
  }
  if (ctHdrFtrRefList.size() > 0) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef[] ctHdrFtrRefs = ctHdrFtrRefList.toArray(new org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef[0]);
   ctSectPrSect1.setHeaderReferenceArray(ctHdrFtrRefs);
  }
  ctSectPrSect1.setFooterReferenceArray(ctSectPrLastSect.getFooterReferenceArray());
 
  //Moving the page settings from last section to new section 1. 
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetPgSz()) ctSectPrSect1.setPgSz(ctSectPrLastSect.getPgSz());
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetPgMar()) ctSectPrSect1.setPgMar(ctSectPrLastSect.getPgMar());
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetPgNumType()) ctSectPrSect1.setPgNumType(ctSectPrLastSect.getPgNumType());
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetCols()) ctSectPrSect1.setCols(ctSectPrLastSect.getCols());
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetDocGrid()) ctSectPrSect1.setDocGrid(ctSectPrLastSect.getDocGrid());
  
  //Setting "there is a title page" for section 1 to make first header work.
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff ctOnOff = org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
  ctOnOff.setVal(true);
  ctSectPrSect1.setTitlePg(ctOnOff);

  //Removing first and old default header references from last section (now section 2) 
  //and setting header reference of even header to be the default header reference for this last section.
  for (int i = ctSectPrLastSect.getHeaderReferenceArray().length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrLastSect.getHeaderReferenceArray(i);
   if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.FIRST) {
    ctSectPrLastSect.removeHeaderReference(i);
    continue;
   }
   if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.DEFAULT) {
    ctSectPrLastSect.removeHeaderReference(i);
    continue;
   }
   if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.EVEN) {
    ctHdrFtrRef.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.DEFAULT); //change this from STHdrFtr.EVEN to STHdrFtr.DEFAULT  
   }
  }
  
  //Unsetting "there is a title page" for the last section.
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetTitlePg()) ctSectPrLastSect.unsetTitlePg();
  
  //Unsetting page numbering type for the last section. So it continues the previous.
  if (ctSectPrLastSect.isSetPgNumType()) ctSectPrLastSect.unsetPgNumType();
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocumentSource.docx"));
  
  addLastPageInSeparateSection(document);
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordDocumentResult.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

If it not works for you, I would need to be able to download your used source Word document somewhere. Then I could get what exactly is the reason why the code is not working using that document.

---

Maybe copying the whole section properties from section below to the new inserted section will be better instead of copying all single section properties. Also the code could be more divided into single methods. This is done in the following code sample. I'll leave the old example for completeness.

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class WordAddLastPageWithoutHeader {
    
 static org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr getDocumentBodySectPr(XWPFDocument document) {
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrDocumentBody = ctBody.getSectPr();
  return ctSectPrDocumentBody;   
 }
    
 static org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr getNextSectPr(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  // get the section settings of next section in document
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrNextSect = null;
  // maybe next section settings are in a paragraph
  XWPFDocument document = paragraph.getDocument(); 
  int pos = document.getPosOfParagraph(paragraph);
  for (int p = pos; p < document.getParagraphs().size(); p++) {
   paragraph = document.getParagraphArray(p);
   if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() != null) {
    ctSectPrNextSect = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getSectPr();   
   }
   if (ctSectPrNextSect != null) break;
  }
  // if not in a paragraph next section settings are in documetn body
  if (ctSectPrNextSect == null) { 
   ctSectPrNextSect = getDocumentBodySectPr(document);
  }
  return ctSectPrNextSect;   
 }
    
 static XWPFParagraph addSectionbreak(XWPFDocument document) {
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = null;;
  // add a paragraph for section settings for new section above and section break.
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // get next section properties, which were section properties for previous section above
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrNextSect = getNextSectPr(paragraph);
  // set a copy of section properties for previous section above as section properties for new section
  if (ctSectPrNextSect != null) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrNewSect = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr)ctSectPrNextSect.copy();
   paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().setSectPr(ctSectPrNewSect);  
   return paragraph;  
  }
  return null;
 }
    
 private static void addLastPageInSeparateSection(XWPFDocument document) {
     
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  XWPFHeader header;
  
  // add a header for even pages, which gets the default header for page in last section later
  header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.EVEN);
  for (int p = header.getParagraphs().size()-1; p >=0; p--) {
   paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(p);
   header.removeParagraph(paragraph);
  }
  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Header EVEN = DEFAULT in last section"); // don't set text here if you wants the header of the page in last section empty.
  
  paragraph = addSectionbreak(document);
  
  if (paragraph != null) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrNewSect = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getSectPr();
   // remove even header and footer from new section
   for (int i = ctSectPrNewSect.getHeaderReferenceArray().length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrNewSect.getHeaderReferenceArray(i);
    if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.EVEN) {
     ctSectPrNewSect.removeHeaderReference(i);
     continue;
    }
   }
   for (int i = ctSectPrNewSect.getFooterReferenceArray().length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrNewSect.getFooterReferenceArray(i);
    if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.EVEN) {
     ctSectPrNewSect.removeFooterReference(i);
     continue;
    }
   }
   // remove first and default header references from last section (now section below the new section) 
   // and set header reference of even header to be the default header reference for this last section
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPrDocumentBody = getDocumentBodySectPr(document);
   if (ctSectPrDocumentBody != null) {
    for (int i = ctSectPrDocumentBody.getHeaderReferenceArray().length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrDocumentBody.getHeaderReferenceArray(i);
     if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.FIRST) {
      ctSectPrDocumentBody.removeHeaderReference(i);
      continue;
     }
     if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.DEFAULT) {
      ctSectPrDocumentBody.removeHeaderReference(i);
      continue;
     }
     if (ctHdrFtrRef.getType() == org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.EVEN) {
      ctHdrFtrRef.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.DEFAULT); //change this from STHdrFtr.EVEN to STHdrFtr.DEFAULT  
     }
    }
    // unset "there is a title page" for the last section.
    if (ctSectPrDocumentBody.isSetTitlePg()) ctSectPrDocumentBody.unsetTitlePg();
    // unset page numbering type for the last section. So it continues the previous.
    if (ctSectPrDocumentBody.isSetPgNumType()) ctSectPrDocumentBody.unsetPgNumType();
   }
   
   try {
    // unset evenAndOddHeaders in settings.xml
    java.lang.reflect.Field _settings = XWPFDocument.class.getDeclaredField("settings");
    _settings.setAccessible(true); 
    XWPFSettings xwpfsettings = (XWPFSettings)_settings.get(document); 
    java.lang.reflect.Field _ctSettings = XWPFSettings.class.getDeclaredField("ctSettings");
    _ctSettings.setAccessible(true); 
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSettings ctsettings = 
     (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSettings)_ctSettings.get(xwpfsettings); 
    if (ctsettings.isSetEvenAndOddHeaders()) ctsettings.unsetEvenAndOddHeaders();
   } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  // content for the last section
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Last page. Page in last section ...");
  //ToDo: further content of last page in separate section

 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocumentSource.docx"));
  
  addLastPageInSeparateSection(document);
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordDocumentResult.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!
A new section is added, a QR is added to it, but for a long time I can not solve the problem. When saving the document in the resulting new document, the number of document pages changes, which is a blocking problem, because the added QR contains the original number of pages of the original document, and the content of the document also becomes invalid, because it contains chapter page numbers and they do not match.
Can you suggest how to get a 100% copy of a document in which the original number of pages is +1 with a QR ?

Comment: Added request 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362506/apache-poi-xwpf-increasing-the-number-of-pages-when-adding-a-new-section

Comment: @Andrei Pastushenko: The code in my answer is minimal complete code to show the principles. It never was thought to be usable as productive code, which is able to work with all possible Word documents, just by copy/paste. The section settings not only provide header/footer settings but page settings too. Those also need to be moved from from last section to new section. Also last section should not have page numbering type. Without a such it continues the previous page numbering type.

Comment: @Andrei Pastushenko: I have updated my answer. Hope it will fit your requirements better now. And please note the last paragraph in my answer. Your new question is missing all the prerequisites to be able to help.

Comment: @Alex Richter, Thank you for your help!
With minor changes, your code gives the desired result. It's great that there are professionals like you who know such specific libraries so deeply.
I apologize for the long response, I was struggling with a related problem that I was able to solve myself. More precisely one decided, the other I have not decided. I'm trying to make the added page of a new section necessarily portrait orientation, as some documents have a landscape [horizontal] orientation as the last page.

Comment: @Alex Richter, In this case, the specified orientation of the QR location on the new page is lost. Found this in the documentation:
`ctSectPrLastSect.getPgSz().setOrient(STPageOrientation.PORTRAIT);`
But alas, this line of code does not work for me and the new page of the new section is also landscape orientation, if the last page of the main source document is also landscape orientation.
What am I missing or where am I not using methods correctly?
Thank you!