# Apache-poi remove or hide footer when long table continues to second page?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, footer

How to remove or hide footer when long table continues to second page?

Example:
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Uez.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I thought I could easily hide or remove footer, but boy I was wrong...
I tried to learn and adapt code examples from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71333447/4806963
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055339/4806963
After trying and failing to understand what and how to change it, I thought I would just put white rectangle and hide it... Found https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857670 ,but I would have to create paragraph and put shape in it and then push it to the bottom of page. Didn't seemed like smart idea, so Im here asking for help...

Comment: First question about such requirements: How would you do this using Microsoft Word's GUI? Apache POI cannot do what Microsoft Word is not able to do.